# DHCP with different range on a bridged router?

Tags: networking

Can I have dhcp enabled on my second router as well as my main router except with different ranges whilst my second router is bridged to the main router?

Comment: If the second router is a bridge, it will have its own subnet and it will support DHCP within that subnet. If it's acting as an access point to the first router's subnet, then DHCP should be disabled and the first router's DHCP should be used for devices attached to the second.

Comment: How do I setup a network bridge using my second router with it's own subnet different than that of my primary router?

Comment: The capabilities of a router are within its firmware: bridging, if it's available, will be under the heading "operating mode" or similar. Your use of the term implies that you have already set bridge mode. What is it that you are really trying achieve for your network overall?

Comment: Well there is a main router from upstairs and I want to bridge the second router downstairs so that there is internet downstairs. But I know people will tend to use the bridged router and just take all the speed for themselves while the others don't have. But since I want internet for the bridged router without internet connectivity problems I have to disable dhcp when I really need it for QoS.

Comment: DHCP is one way to allocate IP addresses, which are necessary for network devices to communicate, but the service levels of these devices are a different matter. Your main router should have bandwidth control settings and it is these which these are used to stop individual devices or groups of them from hogging the network. If you use a bridge, you need to allocate a fixed address to the second router, so you can limit the bandwidth to it. This fixed IP may be set as a reserved value for its MAC address within DHCP, or by setting the bridge itself to have a fixed value outside the DHCP range.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the simple answer is yes you can. 
But it might not give you the result you want.
We need to understand what exactly are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: Upvoting because "A P" is right.  The primary reason to not have multiple DHCP servers on a network is because, if those DHCP servers don't cooperate (which was a historically rare capability), then you could have IP address conflicts.  Still, you run the risk of racing, so a client device may get a quicker response from the other DHCP server when it renews a lease, causing unnecessary address changes. M.B: If you're on one link (thanks to bridging), and can have two DHCP servers, you may want to research using DHCP Failover / redundancy / "load balancing" features of some DHCP server software

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but we need more info on what you're trying to achieve :)
By range, do you mean IPs within the same subnet, or different IP-subnets?
You can have a subnet, for instance 192.168.0.0/24 , with DHCP server A serving 192.168.0.1 - 192.168.0.50 and a DHCP server B serving 192.168.0.51 -192.168.0.99.

Comment: Yes different IP subnets for DHCP server B

Comment: Yes, that's also possible. If you have a server serving 192.168.0.0/24 and a server serving 192.168.1.0/24, the result will be that the DHCP client will randomly (effectively the DHCP server that responds quickest, scores) get a 192.168.0.x IP address or an 192.168.1.x address.

Comment: I have tried bridging it with your ip destinations but I am getting no internet access afterwards